# how can I replace lines from 2 different files using regex in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have 1st file ( Delta_spike_sorted.fasta)with a format of:

```
>lcl|KJ584357.1  
AAAAA 
>lcl|JQ065046.1  
GGGGG
```

and 2nd file (Delta_final.fasta) with the format of:

```
>KJ584357.1 Porcine coronavirus HKU15 strain KY4813, complete genome
TTTTTT 
>JQ065046.1 Magpie-robin coronavirus HKU18 strain HKU18-chu3, complete genome  
CCCCCC
```

I'm trying to write a script to replace the >lcl... of the 1st file with the equivalent title of the 2nd file by matching their IDs (those next to lcl). The final outcome should be something like this:

```
>Porcine coronavirus HKU15 strain KY4813
AAAAA  
>Magpie-robin coronavirus HKU18 strain HKU18-chu3  
GGGGG
```

Now that I see it again, maybe using some hashes would be the most suitable option (sorry for the many mistakes, it's my first post here, also i'm a noob on programming)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open (FIN, "< coronavirus_complete/complete_final/Delta_final.fasta") or die "unable to open FIN \n";
open (FH, "< coronavirus_cds/Spikes/Spikes_complete/sorted/Delta_spike_sorted.fasta") or die "unable 
to open FH \n";

while ($line=<FH>){
    if ($line =~ /^>/){
        chomp($line);
        $acc=substr($line,5,9);
        #print "$acc\n";
    }
    while ($string=<FIN>){
        if ($string =~ /^>/){
        chomp ($string);
        $gen=substr($string,12);
        #print "$gen\n";
    }       
       if ($acc =~ /\Q$string/){
           $line =~ s/$line/$gen/g;
        print "$acc\n";
       }
}
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and add some sample files (not just a vague description) as **text**, no screenshots or similar, and the desired output with that sample files. Also edit the code and give us one that actually compiles, your current one doesn't.

Comment: How large are the files? You're reading through the first file, but consuming the second one as you go along without rewinding it. That's likely not going to work, unless the data you want to match is always in the same line number in both files. Also, please [edit] and show us the expected output.

Comment: What is the expected output for the example files you show?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where I read the definitions from the second file into a hash first. Then you avoid to reread that file for each line in the first file:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{  # <-- scope to prevent local lexical variable to 'leak' into subs below
    my $map = read_fin("Delta_final.fasta");
    my $fn = 'Delta_spike_sorted.fasta';
    open (my $fh, '<', $fn) or die "unable to open file '$fn': $! \n";

    while (my $line=<$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        if ($line =~ /^>/){
            my $acc = substr $line,5,10;
            if (exists $map->{$acc}) {
                say ">$map->{$acc}";
                next;
            }
        }
        say  $line;
    }
    close $fh;
}

sub read_fin {
    my ($fn) = @_;

    my %map;
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        if ( $line =~ /^>((?:\S){10})\s+(\S.*)$/ ) {
            $map{$1} = $2;
        }
    }
    close $fh;
    return \%map;
}
```

**Output**:

```
>Porcine coronavirus HKU15 strain KY4813, complete genome
AAAAA
>Magpie-robin coronavirus HKU18 strain HKU18-chu3, complete genome
GGGGG
```

Comment: How can I print the %map to a new file?

Comment: One simple way to save the output from the program is by using shell redirection. Like this `perl prog.pl > result.txt`